# PHP unlink only works after reload

Tags: php, unlink

My *deletefile.php* has this code.

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$filepath = '/my/path/';
$file = $filepath . $filename;
if(file_exists($file))
{
    unlink($file);
}
?>
```

The variable `$filename` is passed to the script from an href on separate page.

The script works if refresh *deletefile.php* but not when it loads the first time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo` your `$file` on your page and see his value at the first load :-)

Comment: If I echo $filename, $filepath, and $file I see the expected details on first load. They are also there when I refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a previously (on runtime) generated file try calling

```
clearstatcache()
```

before you call

```
file_exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

The results of most file system functions are cached.

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See [`clearstatcache()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.
>
> — [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

`clearstatcache()` clears file status cache.

Note: by default it doesn't clear the realpath cache.

```
void clearstatcache ([ bool $clear_realpath_cache = false [, string $filename ]] )
```